# Filling textarea with Python mechanize module

Tags: python, textarea, mechanize

Is there a way to fill out textarea that is part of form using mechanize module for Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`forms` reference](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) has a couple of examples of filling text controls in `response` objects.

A relevant quote:

```
# The kind argument can also take values "multilist", "singlelist", "text",
# "clickable" and "file":
#  find first control that will accept text, and scribble in it
form.set_value("rhubarb rhubarb", kind="text", nr=0)
```

The `kind` argument can be used with the `form.find_control()` and `form.set_value()` methods to locate `"text"` controls.

Digging a little into the [mechanize `_form.py` source](http://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_form.py), We have an explanation. Mechanize `TextControl` covers (among others) the `TEXTAREA` form element.

```
#---------------------------------------------------
class TextControl(ScalarControl):
    """Textual input control.

    Covers:

    INPUT/TEXT
    INPUT/PASSWORD
    INPUT/HIDDEN
    TEXTAREA

    """
    def __init__(self, type, name, attrs, index=None):
        ScalarControl.__init__(self, type, name, attrs, index)
        if self.type == "hidden": self.readonly = True
        if self._value is None:
            self._value = ""

    def is_of_kind(self, kind): return kind == "text"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://pypi.python.org/pypi")
br.select_form("searchform")
br['term'] = "Mechanize"
response = br.submit()
```

The `br['term'] = "Mechanize"` is the relevant line.

And you seriously need to accept some answers on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can inspect element form first and how many forms in the page can be done with

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```